# How to create multiple unloading dock using the selectOutput block?

Tags: simulation, anylogic, warehouse

I am working on a warehouse simulation model and I cannot figure out how to increase the number of unloading docks while limiting the docks to one supplier truck. I got it working with 2 unloading docks using the select out with the condition is true when Unload_dock_1.isBlocked(). Anyone has tips on how to increase the number of unloading dock while keeping the restriction of 1 truck per unloading dock until released later.

[Current model with two unloading docks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sn4Fd.png)

Kind regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate several blocks into 1 agent and re-use it as many times as you want. Select the blocks, right-click and select "turn into agent" (or similar). Then, you can parameterize that and re-use 2 times, 5 times or 99 times.

Check the Youtube tutorial on the concept: https://youtu.be/0Nu1a9Te6ac

Comment: Thank you for the link to the youtube tutorial, this will be useful. But I still have trouble with how to create multiple unloading areas where the new arriving truck selects an available unloading area. As is done in the picture using a select output block. Any advice ?